# Java Pop-Up Warnings

Tags: java, applet

I just added some Java applets my web and the Java Warnings keep popping up, I am sure this is happening on my clients end as well.  I have read where the manifest file can be edited. I do not where to gfing this file. Installing the the applets into my web created the following files that were uploaded to my server-

```
fpohover.class
fphoverx.class
fprotate.class
fprotatx.class
```

The first two are for link buttons that light up when you hover the mouse over and the last two are for the marquees or picture viewers. If anyone could tell me how to disable the pop ups so I don't worry my potential clients, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use Java applets.  Instead, use Javascript and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

> If anyone could tell me how to disable the pop ups so I don't worry my potential clients..

1. Jump into your time machine and return to that simpler world where Sun/Oracle did not admit that applets could be used by 3rd parties for nefarious ends.
2. Use CSS/JS as suggested by SLaks.

Really, for such cruft in a web page, Java is *overkill.*